# How to copy files to a docker container via docker compose, without binding to host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

IOs are very slow in Docker for Mac due to the overhead of syncing files between the host and container. I want to be able to use docker compose to copy my application files to a certain directory in the container, but WITHOUT any kind of syncing/mounting. If I modify my application, I would just do `docker-compose restart` to create a new container using the updated files. It seems that all docker volume functionality necessitates some kind of syncing to/from the host, which I don't want. How do I accomplish this?

My current volume config, which DOES do syncing, looks like this:

```
volumes:
  - ./application:/var/www/application:cached
```

Comment: Can you delete the `volumes:` setting, COPY your application code in a Dockerfile, and `docker-compose up --build` when your application changes?  That avoids this problem, and has the advantage that the Docker container you’ll be running in this environment exactly matches what you’ll be running in production.

Comment: @DavidMaze I guess that could work, but since docker wouldn't detect any changes in the `Dockerfile`, I'd need to run it with `--no-cache`, and that takes a really long time to build the whole container.

Comment: `docker build` will detect that files you COPY changed, and layer caching will stop at that point: it will COPY in the new files and run any commands beyond that point.

Comment: Try without cached option : **cached: The macOS host’s view of the mount is authoritative. There may be delays before updates made on the host are visible within a container.**

Comment: @SeddikOmar that makes performance worse as there is immediate syncing.

Comment: @DavidMaze I wasn't aware of that. I tried using the COPY method, but it didn't speed things up performance-wise at all, so I'm ending this experiment.